# Getting all data under FireBase user node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve all data under the Attendance node, e.g., "Present", "On Leave", etc.  I then want to show the data in a `ListView` or `RecycleView`. What is the basic logic to do this?

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
package com.example.attendancemanagementsystem;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ViewRecord extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_record);      

    }
}
```

Here is the data being extracted.

[image: I want to take data under "Attendance" with key and value Both]

Comment: Under which Firebase child?

Comment: Under "Attendance"

Comment: So you want to get all those values, `Present`, `On Leave` and so on, right?

Comment: Yes u r right..i want to show them in a listview or recycleview...Alex Mamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, to display all those values in a `ListView`, please use the following code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values;
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference attendanceRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("Attendance");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
            values.add(key + ", " + value);
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
attendanceRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Perfect..Its working i am getting the data now,,,But i want one thing more...I want the values along with the keys...bcz i need the dates that the student is present on or absent,,,How can i do that,,...Thanks alot..

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) In that case, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Wowwww...So quick and so accurate....Thanks alot....Fulfilled my all requirements....

Answer (score 0):

First check for dependencies in your app gradle.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

Initialize variable.

```
private lateinit var mStorageRef: StorageReference
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
```

Then get your firebase database reference.

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

After that get the data you want from that node.

```
StorageRef.child("Users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/attendance")
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?